# difference between two magento login checking code

Tags: magento

I have used two kind of code which check user is logged in (not guest, registered user) or not.
The following are the two source codes.

(1)

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
if( !$customer || !$customerId ) {
    //user is logout
}
else{
    //user is logged-in
}
```

(2)

```
if( !Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() )
{
    //user is logged-in
}
```

I want to know both source codes are doing same thing.
Are both codes certainly checking only registered customer is logged-in or not.
Because i want to reject unregistered(guest user) user from accessing next block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct method to check whether customer logged-in or not.

```
if( !Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() )
{
    //user is logged-in
}
```

The above code is magento inbuilt function to check whether customer logged-in or not.

But the below code is used to get logged-in customer id.

```
$customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
```

If the customer logged-in then it will return the customer id, otherwise return null. So don't use this for check customer logged-in.